# A simple Python program where the user inputs "Heads" or "Tails"

Tags: python

I tried creating a simple Python program where the user inputs their choice of a side of a coin, heads or tails. I tried running it, but the output is consistently "Sadly, that is not the right side!". Could someone please tell me how to improve this code?

```
import random

print ("Pick a side of the coin. Heads or Tails?")
input_coin = input()
input_coin = input_coin.lower
coin = random.choice(["heads", "tails"])

if input_coin == coin:
    print ("You picked the right side!")
else:
    print ("Sadly, that is not the right side!")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As lower is a method inside str you should call it as a method with `()`

Instead of:

```
 input_coin = input_coin.lower
```

type:

```
input_coin = input_coin.lower()
```

As  Baldrickk commented, you can do it with one line instead of two:

```
input_coin = input().lower()
```

If you type: `print (input_coin.lower)`

You will get: `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f901b5c2378>`

Which is not what you expected I guess.

In order to execute the method you need to call it with parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you, this helped fixed it. I forgot I needed to use () at the end of lower.

Comment: or even `input_coin = input().lower()` which produces the lowercase conversion of the input string right off the bat.

Comment: @Baldrickk , Thanks, Added to my answer.